# Css div gets messed up

Tags: html, css

Hey I am making a website and have recently seen some problems With css. My header div Works great maybe because I have styled it With Width 100%. But my main and side div seems to have some problems with the size. I have a Width of 1288px on my main id and when I checked it it is way less. I want my side div to be 30% of the Width of the page and the main div to be 70% of the page. How can I do this?

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

    $tjener = "localhost";
    $brukernavn = "root";
    $passord = "";
    $database = "searchengine";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($tjener,$brukernavn,$passord,$database) or die("could not connect");
    $connection->set_charset("utf8");
    $output = "";
    //collect
    if(isset($_POST["q"])) {
    $searchq = $_POST["q"];

    $searchq = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$searchq);
    $searchq = htmlspecialchars($searchq);
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE vareNavn LIKE '%$searchq%' OR desci LIKE '%$searchq%'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0) {
        $output = "There was no search results.";
    } else {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $id = $row['vareNr'];
            $vareNavn = $row['vareNavn'];
            $desci = $row['desci'];
            $output .= "<h1>" . $vareNavn . "</h1><p> " . $desci . "</p><br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script>

    function active(){
        var Search = document.getElementById("search");
        if(search.value == "Search..."){
            search.value = "";
            search.placeholder = "Search...";
        }
    }
    function inactive(){
        var Search = document.getElementById("search");
        if(search.value == ""){
            search.value = "Search...";
            search.placeholder = "";
        }
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <div id ="searchBar"> 
            <form action="main.php" method= "post">
                <input type="text" id="search" name="q" placeholder="" value="Search..." autocomplete="off" onMouseDown="active();" onBlur="inactive();"/><input type="submit" id="searchButton" value="Search"/>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="oppstart">
            <h1>Newly commenced webstore</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="klokkeMer">
            <h2>Watches</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="div1">

        </div>
        <div id="div2">

        </div>
        <div id="div3">

        </div>
        <?php
        print($output);
        ?>

    </div>

    <div id="side">

    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

and here is my css code:

```
body {
    font-family: arial;
}
h1 {
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
#header {
    width:100%; /* Full lengde*/ 
    background-color:#1F2A40;
    height:100px; /* 150px */
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#search {
        border: 1px solid #1F2A40;
        border-right:none;
        font-size:16px;
        padding:10px;
        outline:none;
        width:700px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft:10px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:10px;
        border-top-left-radius:10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
}
#searchButton {
    border: 1px solid #1F2A40;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:16px;
    background-color:#ff9933;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#1F2A40;
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:none;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
}
#searchButton:hover {
    background-color:#F5870A;
}
#main {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    background-color:red; // change to white when website is done
    width:1288px;
    height:800px;
    left:300px;
}
#side {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    background-color:orange; // change to white when website is done
    width:300px;
    left:0px;
    height:800px;
}
#searchBar {
    position:absolute;
    width:800px;
    top:8px;
    left:250px;
    /* border:1px solid red; */ 
}
#div1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    top:200px;
    left:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100px;
    background-color:purple;
}
#div2 {

}
#div3 {

}
```

Comment: This is a "why isn't my code working?" question, please be more specific. -1

Comment: I want my side div to be 30% of the Width of the page and the main div to be 70% of the page. How can I do this?

Comment: specifying width in pixels might work on your monitor at your resolution, but what happens when someone views it using a different screen resolution? Hint :it's bad!  Try setting widths using percents.. #main{width:100%;}  #side{width:30%;} etc...

Answer (score 1):

Try using percentages for your main and side widths instead of pixels

```
#side{
   width: 30%;
}
#main{
  width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I would do is to scrap most of this css, and use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
This way you get a clean and easy set of tools to use troughout your webpage.

You include the following in your header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

After this, then you use this code:

```
    <div id="side" class="col-md-3">
    Sidebar
    </div>

    <div id="main" class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
        <div id="oppstart">
            <h1>Newly commenced webstore</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="klokkeMer">
            <h2>Watches</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="div1">

        </div>
        <div id="div2">

        </div>
        <div id="div3">

        </div>
        <?php
        print($output);
        ?>

    </div>
```

See it in action here on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LmvoLjcL/)

It might not have your exact dimentions, however this gives you a structered set of rules for your CSS you can use troughout your website